# Automatic pop up window alert box or bootstarp modal alert box based on Timing setting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-2

Hi guys am facing with the problem that I need a pop-up alert box window to raise automatically every day at morning 9:30 am and it should end at 11:30 am in the morning and again afternoon it should raise at 1:30 am to 2:30 add attendance of students.I tried but I have not able to set the timings according to our server timing .please see my code and help me guys and a huge appreciation for them.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="overlay"> <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Context here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>$('#overlay').modal('show');setTimeout(function() {
$('#overlay').modal('hide');}, 5000);
```

Comment: one thing that you need to keep in mind that, your client is unaware of the state/time of the server once is being loaded. if you constantly want to check against server time you need to make multiple calls to the server to check. or you can use js libraries like `moment.js` to do it on your client side

Comment: Hi @Bardia i need to set time and setout time interval based on date() object but still am trying its not coming yar

Answer (score 1):

Since it's longer than a comment i have to post it here,

Let me explain it this way. you need few things before you can get your modal shown on specific time. 
When you load a page and when your code reaches the line that you have `Date()` function it will log that moment of time and that's where it stops.

[image]

And that's where you need some sort of live updating time so that you get live time. for this instance that's why i said you can use library like `moment.js`.

I'll give you both options here: (Vanilla)

```
 function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

setInterval runs the time function every 1 seconds (1000 milliseconds).

to have your function act the way you want you can have an if statement on specific hour and then trigger your modal based on that. and hide it after certain time.

for your if condition you can write it like this :

```
if(d.getHours() == 9 && d.getMinutes() = 30){
  //show modal
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/698686/

Comment: @Bradia let me try and tell the results what else.

Comment: hi @Bradia i tried this code still not working see    <script>
 function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

}
setInterval(time, 1000);

  if(d.getHours() == 12 && d.getMinutes() = 10){
$('#overlay').modal('show');
}
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
</script>

Comment: hi @Bardia  i tried another method also here still not working what can i do  see here the script    <script>
 function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  span.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

}
setInterval(time, 1000);

  if(d.getHours() == 12 && d.getMinutes() = 18){
$('#overlay').modal('show');
}
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
</script>

Comment: the problem was that your if condition was out of the loop and it was not being triggered .

Comment: thank you so much @Bradia its working buddy and huge appreciation from my side you save my day .

Comment: your're most welcome. hopefully someone could save my day by explaining why penguins don't have knees .. oh well!

Comment: ha ha buddy @Bardia